# Replacing placeholder depending on the argument

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the function replace the current placeholder with another depending on the language selected. I'm currently getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined

If I can provide any additional information, let me know.

HTML buttons

```
<input type="button" value="setInputs SI" onclick="setInputs('si')">
<input type="button" value="setInputs AN" onclick="setInputs('an')">
<input type="button" value="setInputs DE" onclick="setInputs('de')">
<input type="button" value="setInputs IT" onclick="setInputs('it')">
<input type="button" value="setInputs HR" onclick="setInputs('hr')">
<input type="button" value="setInputs RU" onclick="setInputs('ru')">
```

HTML form - placeholder

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Janez" 
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Janez'" /><br />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Novak" 
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Novak'" /><br />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus="autofocus" required placeholder="moj@email.com"
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'moj@email.com'" />
```

JS

```
let fname = document.getElementById("fname");   
let lname = document.getElementById("lname");   
let email = document.getElementById("email");   

const placeholders = {
    sl: { fname: "Janez", lname: "Novak", email: "moj@email.si" },
    en: { fname: "John", lname: "Doe", email: "my@email.us" }, 
    de: { fname: "Kommissar", lname: "Rex", email: "mein@email.deu" },
    it: { fname: "Julius", lname: "Cezar", email: "barilla@email.it"},
    hr: { fname: "Mirko", lname: "Mirkic", email: "moj@email.hr"},
    ru: { fname: "Joseph", lname: "Russian", email: "moji@email.ru"}
}; 

function setInputs(language) {
    if (language) {
        const values = placeholders[language];
        fname.setAttribute("placeholder", values.fname);
        lname.setAttribute("placeholder", values.lname);
        email.setAttribute("placeholder", values.email);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I tried to "reverse engineer" the JS function from this one.

```
const lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");

function setLanguage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
        if (lngs[i].className.includes(languageFistTwo)){
            lngs[i].style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            lngs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is `className` defined? I assume you want `elementReference.className....`

Comment: If this is all of your JS code, then you are using the name `className` before it's ever defined.

Comment: this JS is just relevant to this function . I have additinal JS. className is a DOM property...

Comment: `className` is not a DOM property - it is an element property. You must have a specific element that you want to use `className` with. Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Comment: edited the JS and the error message...

Comment: I can begin to understand what you're trying to do but you're going about it the wrong way. It would be great to see the JS in context so I can see where/when the call to `setInputs()` is performed.

Comment: currently I just placed buttons on html until I get it to work. Otherwise they will be linked to the select language button which will toggle between `display: none;` and `display: inline;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you need to search the language in placeholders object. You can check the keys of the object like this:

```
Object.keys(placeholders).includes(language)
```

By the way className you used in your code is usually used in React and is related to CSS class of an element, nothing to do with your placeholders object...

Check the following codepen to see the code running live: https://codepen.io/loic_baron/pen/povGZZw

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll check if I can get it to work.

Comment: Works! Thank you. Could you recommend some articles I could check out so I can understand what is happening behind `Object.keys`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys